# How can get permissions to download images to image gallery?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to download a list of images to the phone image gallery using

> image_gallery_saver: '^1.6.9'

I am trying to get permission using:

> permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1

The following is the code where permissions are requested but the **permission request window** never appears.

The function *downloadProductImages* is called on some buttons in the application.

```dart
Future<List<dynamic>> _downloadFilesList(
    List<Future<Uint8List>> imagesRequests) async {
  final status = await Permission.storage.status;

  print(status.isGranted);
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();
    print(statuses[Permission.storage]);
  }

  final List<Uint8List> files = await Future.wait(imagesRequests);

  return Future.wait(files
      .map(
        (f) => ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
          f,
          quality: 100,
          name: '${getRandString(4)}.jpeg',
        ) as Future,
      )
      .toList());
}

Function downloadProductImages(BuildContext context, Product product) {
  return () async {
    final imagesRequests = product.images.map((img) => _getFile(img)).toList();
    //await _shareFilesList(imagesRequests);
    final result = await _downloadFilesList(imagesRequests);

    var logs = '';
    result.forEach((e) {
      logs = '$logs\n${e.toString()}';
      print(e);
    });

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: SizedBox(
          height: 80,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Text('Las fotos fueron bajadas a tu galleria.\n$logs'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      ),
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission.storage is supported only Android if you test on iOS device you need to add Permission.photo as well

You need to add condition with Platform.isIOS to check with type of permission that you need to use

Comment: My issue is that on Android, I am not getting the window requesting permissions.

Comment: which flutter version that you use? and Do you upgrade your android project to be newer version yet? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects